# Construct Table From Multiple Related XML Files

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have two XML files that represents two relational tables that have relation in between.
The files are as below:
Exam.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Exam>
   <Student id='1'>
     <result>100 </result>
  </Student >
  <Student id='2'>
     <result>200 </result>
  </Student >
 </Exam>
```

Student.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Students>
  <Student id='1'>
      <name>John</name>
  </Student >
  <Student id='2'>
     <name>Mark </name>
  </Student >
```

and the result should be

StudentID StudentName Result

1          John        100

2         Mark        200

How to implement this in c#?
Note: my file are not that simple, so merging them will not be helpful

Comment: You could look into creating XSD's and extracting classes from them with the use of the xsd.exe tool. Then you can serialize to and deserialize from XML files. There's plenty of info on this on the web if you Google the right words.

Answer (score 1):

Linq2Xml can help here.

```
var list = XDocument.Load("student.xml").Descendants("Student")
             .Join(XDocument.Load("exam.xml").Descendants("Student"),
                   x => x.Attribute("id").Value, 
                   y => y.Attribute("id").Value, 
                   (s, e) => new{
                        Name = s.Element("name").Value,
                        Id = s.Attribute("id").Value,
                        Result = e.Element("result").Value
                    })
             .ToList();
```

or the same thing with query syntax

```
var query = from s in XDocument.Load("student.xml").Descendants("Student")
            join e in XDocument.Load("exam.xml").Descendants("Student")
                   on s.Attribute("id").Value equals e.Attribute("id").Value
            select new {
                            Name = s.Element("name").Value,
                            Id = s.Attribute("id").Value,
                            Result = e.Element("result").Value
                       };

var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: and waht does (s, e)  refers to?

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly See the second version. Maybe it can be easier to read.(I used the same variables s & e)

Comment: thanks alot it works :)
but what if the attribute (id) is not found for any node?
a null exception is raised, how to handle it?

Comment: In fact when Id is null you can join two xmls corretly. But you can try appending `.Where(a => a.Attribute("id")!=null)` after `Descendants`

Comment: I need it to reserve row in the list with id cell empty if id is null,just as full join in sql

Comment: please could u give me a link that discuss all those cases to study it? Sorry but this is the first time for me to work with multiple XML files

Answer (score -1):

In this case i Load 2 datatables and programmaticly create a third

loading into a datatable can be done as such

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.ReadXml("FILENAME.xml");
```

and then creating a new datatable programmaticly as such

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName);
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32));
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn("item", typeof(System.String));
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    // Add ten rows.
    DataRow row;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["item"] = "item " + i;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    table.AcceptChanges();
```

If this does not answer your question (You need more detailed explanation) comment on this and ill elaborate for you :)

**And remember, if the question helped, why don't you go ahead and mark it**